# Div with Vertical align set to middle

Tags: html, css

I have div's whose content i want to be vertically centered aligned.

I have applied css with display: table-cell and then set vertical-align: middle but it is not working:

This is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/rBsa2/2/

The content of the div's keep on changing.

In this i want that div with classes "EntryFormControlDiv" and "EntryFormLabelDiv" contents should be vertically aligned inside a div of class: "EntryFormRow".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @utopicam means the textboxes or the textareas divs enclosing the radios comes center aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text in the purple button looks fine to me in the fiddle.

How about adding a line-height?

```
.EntryFormControlDiv
{
    min-height: 50px;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 400px;
    float: left;
    line-height:35px;
}
```

(and some bottom margin in the multiple)

Comment: The div with purple color is not aligned in middle. Notice the "hobbies" div it is not in the middle. In addition i cant use margin bacuse the divs are keep on expanding and contracting since they are populated from the DB

Comment: You can also use line-height for .EntryFormLabelDiv, and it doesn't matter you populate the contents with a DB, you can still add the margin to the class (or a padding to .EntryFormControlDiv)

Comment: My problem is solved, actually i am using the float with the display: table-cell in the CSS classes thats why there are problems. after removing the float and using break tags things are okay. ANyway thanks for help